# Trying to add an active method in a nav-bar with asp attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm kinda new with JavaScript and razor pages and I want to use an attribute or method to show to the user which page they're into,
I have a multiple role page that depends of the role, the page the user can see.
My code is the following:

`

```
                @if (User.IsInRole("Empresa"))
                {
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="home" asp-action="index">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="vacantes" asp-action="index">Vacantes</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="empresas" asp-action="PerfilEmpresa">Perfil</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Cerrar Sesión<i class="bi bi-power"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }

                @if (User.IsInRole("Usuario"))
                {
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="home" asp-action="index">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="vacantes" asp-action="index">Mis Postulaciones</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="" asp-controller="personas" asp-action="PerfilUser">Perfil</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Cerrar Sesión <i class="bi bi-power"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }

                @if (User.IsInRole("SuperUsuario"))
                {
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="paises" asp-action="index">Paises</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="provincias" asp-action="index">Provincias</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="localidades" asp-action="index">Localidades</a></li>
                    <li><a asp-area="" class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="rubros" asp-action="index">Rubros</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-white">Cerrar Sesión <i class="bi bi-power"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        </nav>`  

  `
```

I tried this
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
// Obtener todos los elementos  dentro de la barra de navegación
const links = document.querySelectorAll('nav a');

```
// Inicialmente, ningún enlace está activo
let activeLink = null;

// Agregar un evento 'click' a cada enlace
links.forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        // Evitar la acción predeterminada del enlace
        event.preventDefault();

        // Si ya hay un enlace activo, desactívalo
        if (activeLink) {
            activeLink.classList.remove('active');
        }

        // Activar el enlace clicado
        link.classList.add('active');

        // Almacenar el enlace activo actual
        activeLink = link;

        // Obtener la URL del enlace
        const linkURL = link.getAttribute('href');

        // Redirigir a la URL del enlace
        window.location.href = linkURL;
    });
});
```

});`
and nothing changes.